# How to read from SQL Server Compact Edition file (SDF+Java)?

Tags: java, sql-server-ce

Can anyone tell me how to read data from a `.sdf` file in Java?

Is there any driver compatible for this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no driver for this in Java, SQL Server Compact only runs on Windows platforms. You must expose the data on a Windows machine via some service (WCF/Web API or similar)